# How to control postgres script execution

Tags: versioning, postgresql-9.1

I've a script that I simply paste into an SQL query window in POSTGRES 9.1 and run.

eg
        -- Begin Scripts
        -- Part 1

```
    DO
    $$
    BEGIN
    CREATE SEQUENCE base_listing_id_seq
      INCREMENT 1
      MINVALUE 1
      MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
      START 1
      CACHE 1;
    ALTER TABLE base_listing_id_seq
      OWNER TO postgres;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN duplicate_table THEN RAISE NOTICE 'sequence base_listing_id_seq already exists';
    END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    -- Part 2

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aes_fba_details
    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      product_id integer NOT NULL,
      shippingprice numeric DEFAULT 0,
      fbadatetime date NOT NULL,
      currency text,
      CONSTRAINT aes_fba_details_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
    WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
    );
    ALTER TABLE aes_fba_details
      OWNER TO postgres;

    -- End Scripts
```

What I want to do is to run part 1 or part 2 depending on a value (a version string if you like) that is read in from a table.

eg

```
    myVariable = SELECT version-string FROM versionTable;

    ... 
    DO PART 1
    ...

    If myVariable > 1 then
        ...
        DO PART 2
        ...
    End if
```

Is this even possible?  I apologies in advance if I've mixed up the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you'll need to do all your DDL within a big `DO` block that uses `IF` conditions to decide what to do.

You cannot use variables or `IF` statements in plain SQL, only in PL/PgSQL.

Comment: Thanks, one big DO is fine with me.  Can you help with an outline of what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sai-LeungLee I don't really know what you need. You've pretty much written the code you want. You know how to use PL/PgSQL `DO` blocks, as you have one in your example. So just wrap it in a `DO` block with appropriate `IF ... THEN` conditions. See the manual for PL/PgSQL control structures for how to use an `IF` statement.

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm a little unsure on how to initialise a variable with data returned from an SQL statement: myVariable = SELECT version-string FROM versionTable;  Once I've got this bit working, I'm sure I'll be able to hack together the script.  I know nothig about the DO bits of code (other than what I've been able to cobble together from Google searches).  SQL and functions I'm fine with (to a point) but then I get confused as to how to tie them all together.

Comment: @Sai-LeungLee Please read the PL/PgSQL manual for details. Look at the `DECLARE` statement and the `SELECT ... INTO ...` statement for PL/PgSQL (this is different to normal SQL `SELECT ... INTO ...`)